# ImageButton from gridview not working for onClick Event with RowCommand of gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am using a image button inside a GridView like

```
<asp:ImageButton ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Captions,lbledit%>" ID="imgbtnPopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%$ Resources:Paths,imgbtnEdit%>"   CommandName="callPopup" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WOID")  %>' CssClass="imgActions" OnClientClick="Popup.show('simplediv');return false;" />
```

on `OnClientClick` event when i wrote return false it was not firing `RowCommand` event of the GridView

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain so I won't make this an answer, but I believe returning false cancels the postback event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove return false; then it should work fine.

Comment: after removing return false the div (simplediv) is getting displayed for few minutes only and gets removed from the screen. please anyone help me